# Ignore some of the model properties in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So let's say that I have two classes, A and B

```
public class A
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string? User {get; set;} 
}
```

```
public class B : A
{
  public string? Name {get; set;}
  public string? City {get; set;}
  public bool IsActive {get; set;}
}
```

I'm using code first approach in a EF Core application, and I don't want my entity to have the property `User` that is getting by inheritance from class A.

Is there a way to ignore that property WITHOUT MODIFYING class `A`?

Comment: _"I don't want my entity to have the property User"_ -  you mean that you don't want corresponding column created in database?

Comment: @GuruStron exactly, that's my issue

Comment: @DenisMicheal it will require modifying base class though (and OP explicitly asked for option without that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the fluent API since you can't set the NotMapped Attribute.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<B>().Ignore(b => b.User);
}
```

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ignore-method

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the [`EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>.Ignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.ignore?view=efcore-8.0) method from the Fluent API. For example in the `OnModelCreating` call:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
        .Ignore(b => b.User);
}
```

See the [`Included and excluded properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=fluent-api%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties) section of the EF Core documentation.